# jQuery hover functions IE error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been having some difficulty with jQuery hover functions. Proberbly as a result of staring at the same code for far too long, but perhaps someone can help.

I have the following function:

```
    $("#div1").mouseover(function () {
        $("#div2:hidden").show();
    });
    $("#div1").mouseout(function () {
        $("#div2:visible").hide();
    });
```

Which I have also tried as:

```
    $("#div1").hover(function () {
        $("#div2:hidden").show();
    }, function() {
        $("#div2:visible").hide();
    });
```

Neither work AT ALL in IE. Everything I write using ANY mouseover, hover, mouseout or any other "mouse" function causes errors in IE. With other browsers it is perfect and what's more annoying is it occasionally works in IE, for instance on occasion the first and second time it will work - then it will error.

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: can you provide the markup, i hope you are not using the identical `id`s (just a hunch)

Comment: Agree about the possibility of using identical `id` values. Also, you don't need the `:hidden` and `:visible` in there. Whether the div is hidden or not, `.show()` will do the same thing. Likewise for `.hide()`.

Comment: Sadly not, the ID's are all given very specific names (all W3 valid). I've ran a search in visual studio and there are no multiple instances of ID usage. I've removed the ":hidden / :visible" selectors, no change. But thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works just fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/U89de/1/

Your first code is wrong. Better is using:

```
$('#div1').mouseover(function() {
  // mouseover event
}).mouseout(function() {
  // mouseout event
});
```

---

If you use jQuery 1.7 or higher it's better to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$('#div1').on({
  mouseover : function() {
    // mouseover event
  },
  mouseout : function() {
    // mouseout event
  }
});
```

Comment: I updated it to the .on() function - same error. Works fine in every other browser.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Have you put a $(document).ready event around your code? Have you added the JS code just before </body>?

Comment: Yes to both. It just triggers and object expected error in IE, I've tried 6/7/8/9, no change even when stripped down so there is nothing else on the page. I'm thinking there may be something wrong with my IE.

Comment: Can you give an live example of your code? (on JSfiddle) And do you also get the error when you use our live examples on JSfiddle? What version of IE do you have?

Comment: Your link http://jsfiddle.net/U89de/1/ is as close to mine as you can get, except mine shows on hover while yours hides on hover. I have the latest version of IE9, this error could have started since the last update - I'm just reinstalling now.

Answer (score 0):

somethig else is wrong its working here

http://jsfiddle.net/TnPRA/4/

EDIT

one more thing wrap your code inside the ready handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//your code here
});
```

because this here does not work that is its not wrapped inside the ready handler notice the `no wrap(head)` option in the second fiddle

as a proof of concept follow the link  http://jsfiddle.net/TnPRA/10/

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something but I don't see why you are specifying the visibility of div2 w/in the selector.  The following should work just fine:

```
$("#div1").mouseover(function () {
    $("#div2").show();
});
$("#div1").mouseout(function () {
    $("#div2").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace all $ symbols with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with IE11, and changing all $ to jQuery fixed the issue. For some reason IE was not working well with the shorthand $.

Answer (score -1):

try removing :hidden and :visible from selectors.
You are using an ID to reference your object, in this case you don't need id.

```
$("#div1").hover(function () {
    $("#div2:hidden").show();
}, function() {
    $("#div2:visible").hide();
});
```

Best regards, Davide

Comment: **Quote:**  _"in this case you don't need **id**"_.... what are you talking about?  You just reposted the OP's code; how does that help anyone?

Comment: it was a typing error, "in this case you ton't need them" in reference to :visible and :hidden selectors.

Answer (score -1):

check your DOCTYPE, in this case your example uses:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Only <!doctype html> is enough. A browser doesn't anything with all the stuf between ""...

Comment: It was XHTML 1.0T, I've changed it to strict - however there is no change.